# Regex in JS - Add match to replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't find the solution to this anywhere, but I think it's because I don't have the terminology right.

I have this:

```
var text = "Foo:Bar"; // I want -> "Foo: Bar"
text = text.replace(new RegExp("Foo:[a-z]", "ig"), "Foo: ");
```

I have lots of `foo`s, and I want to add a space after the colons. I only want to do it if I can tell the colon has a letter right after it. However, when I do the above, I get:

```
// -> "Foo: ar"
```

How do I take that `[a-z]` match, and throw it into the end of the replace?

Comment: Whats wrong with the regex you have? Just add a capture group. `text = text.replace( /Foo:([a-z])/ig, 'Foo: $1');`

Comment: @sin, I didn't know what a capture group was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `[a-z]` in your regex consumes an alphabet but a lookaround won't consume a character. `(?=[a-z])` this positive lookahead asserts that the match (`Foo:`) must be followed by an alphabet. So this regex will match all the `Foo:` strings only when it is followed by an alphabet. Replacing the matched `Foo:` with `Foo:<space>` will give you the desired output.

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp("Foo:(?=[a-z])", "ig"), "Foo: ");
```

OR

```
text = text.replace(/Foo:(?=[a-z])/ig, "Foo: ");
```

Comment: ++ for nailing it, and for telling me what it's called. That worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple capturing group and reference it as `$1` in replace string:

```js
var text = "Foo:Bar"; // I want -> "Foo: Bar"
text = text.replace(new RegExp("Foo:([a-z])", "ig"), "Foo: $1");

alert(text);
```

Also I would use regexp literal expression instead of contructor:

```
text = text.replace(/Foo:([a-z])/ig, "Foo: $1");
```

Comment: This is what I was originally thinking of. Thanks and I'll use that in the future!